# VBA work fine in Microsoft word but not working in Libre office writer how to fix

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I use this code to replace text in word file its work fine in Microsoft Office but have not work on Libre office writer'

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim AppWord As Word.Application

Set AppWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

AppWord.Activate

Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

With ActiveDocument.Range.Find

      .Text = rep.TextBox1.Value
      .Replacement.Text = rep.TextBox2.Value
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    rep.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is this tagged **excel** when tthe question is apparently about Word?

Answer (score 1):

No real experience, really. But OO and LO incorporate (limited) direct support for VBA (language and office object model). This is used with MS native file formats automatically. In ODF/ODS files you have to enable VBA support at the beginning of the macro, otherwise it expects LO-Basic:

```
Option VBASupport 1
Option Compatible
```

But be prepared for difficulties. And keep in mind that LO does not store its own macros in MS office file formats. Conversion to the LO-Basic and UNO object model have to be done by hand, although there is a simple online converter from [business-spreadsheets.com](https://www.business-spreadsheets.com/).

### Reply to your comment :

In your case, I think just put : `Option VBASupport 1` to enable VBA support at the beginning above your first `Sub` by Libre Office. You can find more information [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/he/text/sbasic/shared/03103350.html)

Comment: Hi good day thank you for your response.Can you  change the code to work in Libre office writer